# Mimicking iOS notification view

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewanimation

I am trying to mimic iOS 5's notification view (when you swipe down the view appears) for hub with a left swipe in my view. I created a mimic for a single view controller by adding the hubview as subview and changing the origin of view when making swipe. But With this approach I have to add it to every view I implement in my app. I want to add it to `UIViewController` as a category. I am not sure how to proceed at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want every viewController to have to handle the menu then I would suggest having a root viewController that acts like a container.  It has a subview that displays the content from your various view controllers and it also has the controls for your menu and any other overlay information you may want to provide.

Answer (score 0):

A category won't work in this case but subclassing will. Just ensure that all of your view controllers are sub classes of the view controller with this functionality implemented.